# Trying to reference a cell in importxml

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-finance

My B3 is CULP. It's a stock ticker symbol. This import XML is supposed to get the annual dividend yield number which is 5.76%, but I'm getting an error instead which states "imported content is empty" Getting the annual dividend yield works when I don't try to reference the B3 cell so scraping is compatible with this webpage. There's something wrong with how its trying to get a value from B3.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&B3, "/html/body/div[4]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/b/span")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&B3, "table", 7), 8, 2), "*", )
```

[image]

Comment: Ok got it. This works. Thanks for the help!